# Display four lineChart() in different windows or simultaneously in R and ESS, quantmod

Tags: r, quantmod, ess

How can I display these four lineChart() simultaneously or in one window ?

Having this code in one file:

```
library(quantmod)

getSymbols("XPT/USD",src="oanda") 
getSymbols("XAU/USD",src="oanda")

lineChart(XAUUSD, subset='2018-03::2018-03') 
lineChart(XAUUSD, subset='2018-04::2018-04') 
lineChart(XPTUSD, subset='2018-03::2018-03')
lineChart(XPTUSD, subset='2018-04::2018-04')
```

When I evaluate the buffer it displays only the last lineChart.

Is this a property of ESS ? I want to clarify that I need the four graphs separately.

Comment: `plot.xts` will give you a line chart. I.e. to chart XPT for the month of March: `plot.xts(XPTUSD['2018-03’])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quantmod plotting functions, nice and powerful as they are, will not respect `par(c(mfrow()))` or the equally nice (but less well-known `layout()`) so you have to create new plotting devices -- via `x11()` or `window()`-- and arrange them via your operating system / window manager.

For me:

```
R> x11(); lineChart(XAUUSD, subset='2018-03::2018-03')
R> x11(); lineChart(XAUUSD, subset='2018-04::2018-04') 
R> x11(); lineChart(XPTUSD, subset='2018-03::2018-03')
R> x11(); lineChart(XPTUSD, subset='2018-04::2018-04')
```

yielded

[image]

and note that these are *four* distinct window. See `dev.new()` and `dev.next()` and those functions.